# Python: when I extract a number using findall() the output is " [ ' 39772 ' ] " how do I get rid of " [ ' ' ] " so I can convert to float?

Tags: python, floating-point, format, findall

I'm using re.findall() to extract a number from lines in a file & I can get the number just fine, but the function adds quotes and double quotes and square brackets so that I can't convert the string to float. How do I strip the " [ '  ' ] " characters from the number so I can convert it?

Here's my code:

```
import re
count = 0
total = list()
hand = open('mbox-short.txt')
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('New Revision: ([0-9.]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        count += 1
        a = str(x)
        total.append(a)
    
print(total)     # test print

total1 = list(map(float, total))          # line 24 -- where I get the ValueError

print(sum(total1)/count)
```

---

output:

```
["['39772']", "['39771']", "['39770']", "['39769']", "['39766']", "['39765']", "['39764']", " 
['39763']", "['39762']", "['39761']", "['39760']", "['39759']", "['39758']", "['39757']", " 
['39756']", "['39755']", "['39754']", "['39753']", "['39752']", "['39751']", "['39750']", " 
['39749']", "['39746']", "['39745']", "['39744']", "['39743']", "['39742']"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "revisions.py", line 27, in <module>
    total1 = list(map(float, total))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ['39772']
```

---

[link to file 'mbox-short.txt'](https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt)

I'm trying to convert the numbers to float so I can compute the average.
What am I missing? Where can I find info on manipulating the format of the output so I can use it?

Thank you!

Comment: dont do ```a = str(x)``` and directly append ```x```

Comment: it wouldn't let me; I got an error about tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use list comprehension to convert all values in `total` to float.

```py
total = [float(i.split("'")[1]) for i in total]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "['123']"

s = s[2:-2] # remove first 2 and last 2 characters

print(float(s))
# 123.0
```

Just strip the first and last 2 characters from the string.